# Find and replace the string in paragraph

Tags: c#, string

I want to empty the value between the hyphn for example need to clear the data in between the range of  hyphen prefix and suffix then make it has empty string.

```
string templateContent = "Template content -macro- -UnitDetails- -testEmail- sending Successfully";
```

Output

```
templateContent = "Template content sending Successfully";
```

Comment: Suppose My input is Like that is there

string templateContent = "Template content-macro--UnitDetails--testEmail- sending Successfully";

At the time its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, however given your example the following should work

```
var split = templateContent
      .Split(' ')
      .Where(x => !x.StartsWith("-") && !x.EndsWith("-"));

var result = string.Join(" ",split);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
Template content sending Successfully
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CiRriU)

<sub>***Note** : I personally think regex is better suited to this*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```cs
templateContent = Regex.Replace(templateContent, @"-\w*-\s?", string.Empty).TrimEnd(' ');
```

`@"-\w*-\s"` - is regex pattern for '-Word- '
`-` - pattern for `-`
`\w` - [word character](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp).
`*` - zero or any occurrences of `\w`
`\s` - pattern for [whitespace character](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)
`?` - marks `\s` as optional
`TrimEnd(' ')` - to remove trailing space if there was a pattern at end of the string

Comment: This pattern can be simplified to `-\w*-\s` or `-\S*-\s`...

Comment: Upvoted for being the only regex based answer that provides the desired results and explains the pattern (though I still think the pattern should be simplified).

Comment: Putting \s at the end of the regex would prevent it from finding a match at the end of the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultWithSpaces = Regex.Replace(templateContent, @"-\S+-", string.Empty);
```

This regular expression looks for two hyphens surrounding one or more characters that are not white space.

It will leave the spaces that were around the removed word. To get rid of those you can do another Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(resultWithSpaces, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: This will result in `Template content    sending Successfully` (too many spaces....)

Comment: Also, `[^\s]+` can be simplified to `\S+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this

```
    string regExp = "(-[a-zA-Z]*-)";
    string tmp = Regex.Replace(templateContent , regExp, "");
    string finalStr = Regex.Replace(tmp, " {2,}", " ");
```